# Sonarqube server with or without internet connection

Tags: sonarqube

I´m new with sonar and I have started to define my environment and requirements for a first installation.

My question is, really the server need to have a internet connection? or only is used for install plugins and updates?.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An uplink to the Internet definitely is **not** a requirement for SonarQube. If available then it'll be used by the SonarQube [Update Center](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Update+Center), otherwise you can just install/upgrade plugins [manually](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Update+Center#UpdateCenter-ManualUpdates).

Comment: but is the internet connection recommended? will i lose some other functionality? thx